# Receive email notifications when an answer is edited

Tags: feature-request, notifications, email-notification

I've asked one question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735339/gmail-snooze-error-movesnoozes-service-invoked-too-many-times-in-a-short-time/)). Someone had kindly given an answer to my question. Consequently, I am alerted through my Stack Exchange inbox, on the upper-left corner. If I so choose, I would also receive an an email in my real email address (e.g. GMail) alerting me that I have a new Stack Exchange message.

However, when that answer-giver edited his answer and made it more helpful, I received no notification in my Stack Exchange inbox, nor did I have an option for receiving emails about this edit.

I had to visit my question manually to see if there was any changes. And, yes, there it was! I really wish we didn't have to manually check our questions to see if any answer-giver has edited his answer.

Could you please allow us to receive email notifications when someone edits their answers to our questions (or to any question we are following)?

Comment: It's the answer author responsibility to comment and let you know he/she made an edit.

Comment: Hi, I like your writing style but it's not completely necessary. Look at Bart's edit on this question and mine on your question on Stack Overflow. Details are what's important; it helps everyone help you better.

Comment: And not to stray too far off-topic, but some of @ben's and my edits are explained here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts